# minimum number of neighbors based minimum degree of vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph of $n \geq 4 $

Where $\delta (G) \geq \frac {2n+1}{3} $

Let $(u,v)$ be an edge, and let $N(u)$ and $N(v)$ be the neighbours of $u$ and $v$ amongst $V(G)\setminus \{u,v\}.$ Show that $$\left|N(u)\cap N(v)\right|\geq \frac{n+2}{3}\geq 2.$$

Any idea how they are coming up with the $\frac{n+2}{3} $ lower bound from $\delta (G) \geq \frac {2n+1}{3} $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just PIE. We know that $|N(A)\cup N(B)| \leq n$. So we have $$n\geq |N(A)\cup N(B)|= |N(A)|+| N(B)| -|N(A)\cap N(B)| \geq 2\cdot {2n+1\over 3}-|N(A)\cap N(B)| $$

and thus $|N(A)\cap N(B)|\geq  {n+2\over 3}$